# Stored procedure passing like statement in case

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ViewSo]
    @Dt1 as datetime,
    @Dt2 as datetime,
    @CusName as nvarchar,
    @so_no as nvarchar
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             0 as stat,
             m.id, f.id as fg_id, f.fg_des, m.so_no,
             Replace(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CAST(m.so_date AS DATE) , 106),' ','-') AS so_date,
             Convert(NVARCHAR,CAST(m.so_date AS DATE),101) AS so_date1,
             m.cus_name, m.so_cus_id, m.doc_no, m.sale_person, m.so_rem,
             f.fg_des AS eXP1, f.fg_qty,
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(f.req_date AS DATE), 101) AS req_date,
             CASE 
                WHEN COALESCE (q.tot_req_qty, 0) < f.fg_qty 
                   THEN 'Not Updated' 
                   ELSE 'Updated' 
             END AS req_qty_stat,
             'SO No :' + CONVERT(varchar(15), m.so_no) + '/SO Date :' + CONVERT(varchar(15), REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CAST(m.so_date AS DATE), 106), ' ', '-')) + '/Cus Name :' + CONVERT(varchar(15), m.cus_name) + '/Sales Prsn :' + CONVERT(varchar(15), m.sale_person)  AS filter ,
             f.fg_no,m.so_stat,
             m.del_flag, m.st_stat, m.st_rem    
         FROM   
             so_mas AS m 
         INNER JOIN   
             so_fg AS f ON m.id = f.so_id 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN    
             (SELECT        
                  fg_id, SUM(req_qty) AS tot_req_qty     
              FROM   
                  fg_qty
              WHERE        
                  (del_flag = 0)    
              GROUP BY fg_id) AS q ON q.fg_id = f.id  
         WHERE
             m.del_flag = 0) AS S 
    WHERE
        CONVERT(datetime, s.so_date) BETWEEN @Dt1 AND @Dt2  
        AND S.cus_name LIKE 
                  CASE WHEN @CusName = '' THEN S.cus_name 
                       ELSE +'%' + @CusName + '%'  
                  END
    ORDER BY 
        s.so_date;
END
```

This is my stored procedure passing like statement in case. If run as query it works fine. If I used as stored produce leads to wrong result.

Please help me to solve.

Comment: Please try to create a *minimal* example of what you're trying to do. I've got no idea at the moment. Also, you've almost certainly misdeclared your parameters, unless you *intention* is that `@CustNo` and `@so_no` should only contain up to 1 character. Please see [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: Your code is very hard to read as well. Make sure you format it better so we can clearly read and know what is being wrong. Also I have noticed multiple WHERE statements I suggest you use HAVING instead.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this part of `WHERE`

```
AND S.cus_name LIKE 
              CASE WHEN @CusName = '' THEN S.cus_name 
                   ELSE +'%' + @CusName + '%'  
              END
```

With

```
AND S.cus_name LIKE 
              CASE WHEN @CusName = '' THEN S.cus_name 
                   ELSE '%' + @CusName + '%'  
              END
```